# how to group array and read using knockout.js data-bind: with

Tags: arrays, json, knockout.js

I am trying to group an array

```
[{ "Name": "test1", "Other": "Junk" }, 
{ "Name": "test1", "Other": "Junk2" }, 
{ "Name": "test2", "Other": "Pile" }]
```

I am using the following method to group by property.

```
var groupBy = function (xs, key) {
return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
    }, {});
};
```

My output from this is, "test1": {children info}, "test2": {one child info}

I am using knockout.js to pass this info to a modal, to which i am using data-bind="with: results"

I am just not sure how to display the results as

test1 - (2) *count/length of test1
test2 - (1) *count/length of test2

I have tried using data-bind="foreach: $parent", this doesn't seem to work.  I have also tried setting the object, to a parent called UnpackedItems, then using foreach on UnpackedItems.. this doesn't work either.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-bind="with: TheseUnpackedItems" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Unpacked Items</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table style="margin: auto;" class="table">
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: UnpackedItems">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: Name"></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
self.ShowUnpacked = function(vm) {

  var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  };

  const Property = "Name";
  const GroupedUnpackedItems = groupBy(vm.UnpackedItems, Property);

  var test = JSON.stringify(GroupedUnpackedItems);

  var m = { "UnpackedItems": GroupedUnpackedItems }

  self.TheseUnpackedItems(vm);
}
```

I am not getting any errors, however, no data actually shows up.

Comment: Where is `var m = { "UnpackedItems": GroupedUnpackedItems }` being used?

Comment: sorry, its being used `self.TheseUnpackedItems(m);`

Comment: If I pass `vm`, i can read it, but if i pass `m` I am unable to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnpackedItems` is an object. So, you can't use `foreach` bindings. You could loop through the keys of the object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Object.keys(UnpackedItems)">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: $data"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
  
function viewModel() {
  const self = this;
  const UnpackedItems=[{Name:"test1",Other:"Junk"},{Name:"test1",Other:"Junk2"},{Name:"test2",Other:"Pile"}],
    Property = "Name",
    GroupedUnpackedItems = groupBy(UnpackedItems, Property),
    m = { "UnpackedItems": GroupedUnpackedItems }

  self.TheseUnpackedItems = ko.observable(m);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel)
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" data-bind="with: TheseUnpackedItems">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Unpacked Items</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table style="margin: auto;" class="table">
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: Object.keys(UnpackedItems)">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: $data"></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well, thank you.  Object.keys works great!